# Comparison of timestamps in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've got following data as result from a query. As example 2 rows but in total around 30000 rows.
Some timestamps are empty because no row in that table.

| agr_no | timestamp1 | timestamp2 | timestamp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000080064 | 2005-08-17-09.29.01.427337 |  | 2005-08-17-09.29.01.351888 |
| 00000080065 |  | 2002-04-29-15.04.58.714606 | 2013-11-18-13.11.46.494690 |

I would like to have in the next column an indication about which timestamp is the greatest.
For example:

| agr_no | timestamp1 | timestamp2 | timestamp3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000080064 | 2005-08-17-09.29.01.427337 |  | 2005-08-17-09.29.01.351888 | TS1 |
| 00000080065 |  | 2002-04-29-15.04.58.714606 | 2013-11-18-13.11.46.494690 | TS3 |

Tried many things but always in trouble with the format of the timestamp so no comparison is possible.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the standard for the date format? Is the maximum date to be extracted in a single column or in multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

*This is quite ugly but,*

You can convert your values to dates and then just take the max date, or in this instance, the index of the matched date.

[image]

```
="TS" & MATCH(MAX(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:C2,10))+TIME(MID(A2:C2,12,2),MID(A2:C2,15,2),MID(A2:C2,18,2)+(RIGHT(A2:C2,6)/1000)),0)),IFERROR(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2:C2,10))+TIME(MID(A2:C2,12,2),MID(A2:C2,15,2),MID(A2:C2,18,2)+(RIGHT(A2:C2,6)/1000)),0),0)
```

---

Note this assumes the formats of the string dates are either blank OR in strictly in the below format which is consistent with the limited inputs you gave us

`yyyy-mm-dd.hh.mm.ss.######`

---

FYI - Your milliseconds value is strange. On your first row the milliseconds actually equates to minutes

Comment: In short the formula is following the logic of the `MATCH(MAX())` formula *([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641062/6706419))*. This just gets very long because the range has to be converted to datetime in the `MATCH` and `MAX` formula. This can be greatly shortened if you can think of a shorter way to convert your strings to datetime

Comment: Doesn't Datevalue also depend on your system date format settings?  Though I think its a lot shorter/cleaner then shoving all the date bits into DATE.

Comment: potentially shorter time conversion since you already used DATEVALUE:  `TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2:C2,12,8),".",":")&RIGHT(A2:C2,7))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is located at `[A1:D27]` and based on this formula to convert the `string` TimeStamp to a `double`:

```
= IFERROR( VALUE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( B2,
           "-", " ", 3 ), ".", ":" ), ":", ".", 3 ) ), 0 )
```

Enter this `FormulaArray` in `E2`, then copy `E2` downwards till last row:

```
= "TS" & MATCH( MAX(
  IFERROR( VALUE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( B2:D2,
           "-", " ", 3 ), ".", ":" ), ":", ".", 3 ) ), 0 ) ),
  IFERROR( VALUE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( B2:D2,
           "-", " ", 3 ), ".", ":" ), ":", ".", 3 ) ), 0 ), 0 )
```

`FormulaArray` are entered holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>  simultaneously, the formula would be wrapped within `{` and `}` if entered correctly.

[image]