# Excel column references (instead of value)

Tags: excel, reference, formula

I am searching for a way to obtain column-references in Excel.

I would like to search through a row (B12:G12) and look for the highest number. That could be done with the MAX-formula. But instead of the value, I would like to get the column reference of that cell, like B, C, D, E, F, G.
Is there a way to do that? I already tried the Address-/ and Index-formula, but that didn't work.

Thanks a lot and greetings!
[image: Edit]

Answer (score 1):

This will tell you what Column Index has the max value inside the array.

```
=MATCH(MAX(B12:G12),B12:G12)
```

Note the index here starts at `B = 1, C = 2, etc.` so if you want the actual column index *(i.e. such that `A = 1`)* then just add 1 to the end of the equation

---

You can also output the actual column letter reference by associating the value to the `CHAR` index with

```
=CHAR(MATCH(MAX(B12:G12),B12:G12)+65)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Note the `CHAR` index method won't work when you get into double letter columns such as `AA, AB, AC, etc.`.  The index only spans `A-Z` - other values are just combinations. Assuming your example is sufficient then just should work

Comment: Hello, first, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I encountered something very strange. Although the formula is the same in column I (with only the reference of the row changing), I obtain cells with a #NV remark. Could you please help me with that? I tried everything, but it does not change. I pasted a screenshot of my window in the description. Instead of the MAX-, I now use the MIN-formula, but that must not be the point ;)

Comment: You cannot just change the question and then unaccept  solutions that answered what you asked for.

Comment: If you have a different question then you should make a new post. That’s how this site works.